# I get error message "Permission denied (publickey)" when I was using the newest git on windows

Tags: git

Everything was fine when I was using git 2.29.2.windows.3.

But it got a error message about permission denied when I updated it to 2.38.1.windos.1.

The ssh key doesn't changed. Anybody Knows what's the reason?

p.s. I am using RSA algorithm to generate my ssh key(`ssh-keygen` no other arguments)
Here is the result of `ssh -v git@e.coding.net`

```
git clone git@e.coding.net:deagrace/test/test1.git
Cloning into 'test1'...
git@e.coding.net: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: To distinguish between ssh issues and git issues, try to connect with command line ssh client : `ssh -v git@<remote-server>`. If this works : you have an issue with git ; if this doesn't work : fix your ssh setup.

Comment: For GitHub, the correct command to test is `ssh -vT git@github.com`.

Comment: @LeGEC I tried to connect with ssh cli and it works. But I still dont know what's the problem of git.

Comment: Can you paste the error message you see ?

Comment: @LeGEC thanks for your reply. I paste the error message in my question. I used the same key in my Linux server to clone the same repository. It works fine.

Comment: @LeGEC I found the problem. OpenSSH 8.8​ stopped supporting RSA-SHA1 algorithm. I just need to change its algorithm